# What is the deal with .bashrc and .bash_profile on MacOS?

Tags: macos, alias, macos-catalina

I am very lost about my .bashrc and .bash_profile. I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.5.

I have created a .bash_profile file in my home folder that contains the following:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then                                                        
 source ~/.bashrc                                                                
fi
```

and a .bashrc file containing the following:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/xavierfrehner"
alias ls='ls -Ga'
```

Whenever I restart the terminal/restart the computer, my alias that I've created does not work.

No matter what I look up I can't seem to find an actual run down of what needs to be done in order to get a bashrc file working.

I am aware of the bashrc file in my /etc/ folder, and whenever I changed this using root privileges, my alias still does not work.

If someone could help explain to me what I need to do, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc#:~:text=bash_profile%20is%20executed%20for%20login,before%20the%20initial%20command%20prompt.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already been asked and answered on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036).

Comment: are you actually running bash?  default shell on catalina is `zsh`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's more likely OP is using zsh rather than bash, so it uses different init scripts. See: [What are the practical differences between Bash and Zsh?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-bash-and-zsh)

Comment: I agree that it sounds more plausible, but the question is still written around bash, so once verified he should rewrite his question. It might still be better asked on AskDifferent though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are running Catalina on a Mac, using terminal you might be leaning towards creating a .bashrc file and implementing aliases in the typical linux way, and what is written will work properly in a typical unix shell. However, the issue arises in the fact that Catalina is not directly using bash in the default terminal.

Catalina and beyond use zsh as their default shell, and thus does not use a bash shell, you will need to be creating a .zshrc file instead.

Syntax is familiar if you have worked with bash, and aliases particularly will work the same way as they would in bash.

Comment: You can also tell macos to use bash as your default on Catalina, that is what I do. At the moment I don't recall how I did that. Please Duckduckgo it to find out.